# RequestReduce PageFilter works on http but not https

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, requestreduce

I'm using RequestReduce (http://requestreduce.org/) to bundle and minify but have a bit of an odd issue.

I'm using a page filter to exclude a part of my site from RequestReduce processing as follows:

```
Registry.AddFilter(new PageFilter(x => x.HttpRequest.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/myzone/")));
```

But while this works fine when I access the site over http it still seems to serve "Reduced" content when accessing over https. Have I missed something obvious here?

EDIT: I've also tried the following in case it was related to the slashes or use of RawUrl.  No dice.  Unfortunately RequestReduce seems to blindly run on all https pages no matter what I put in for the page filter:

```
Registry.AddFilter(new PageFilter(x =>x.HttpRequest.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("myzone")));
```